# Animation in ScrollView is missing the last object in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, core-animation

I'm trying to create a list of objects that when filled every object will have an animation with a delay depending on its position in the array.

To replicate my problem here's the code:

```
struct ScrollViewTest: View{
    
    @State private var indexes = [Int]()
        
    var body: some View{
        VStack{
            ForEach(indexes, id:\.self){ index in
                Text("Index: \(index)")
                    .transition(.opacity)
            }
            
        }
        .onAppear {

            for index in 0..<9{
                withAnimation(Animation.easeInOut.delay(Double(index) * 0.5)){
                    indexes.insert(index, at: index)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, `Index 8` is already visible before the animation even started.
How do I solve this kind of problem?

Comment: you are animating the insertion into an array — how do you expect this animation to look like?

Comment: Because I want the animation to look staggering. So I want to use the index for it.

Comment: Can you add a video to show how does it look for you? It works as expected in Xcode 12.3, iOS 14.3.

Answer (score 0):

I am not seeing an issue on Swift 5, Xcode version 12.3.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, this problem occurs only on the live preview.
My mistake was that I determined that there is a problem because I used the live preview to examine the animation.